# Unable to access the documents in streambuilder

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout

Hey guys I was trying to build a streambuilder to access my cloud storage but I am unable to do streamsnapshot.data.doc due to that I am not able to use the documents for my application

This is my streambuilder code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class ChatScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChatScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore
            .instance 
            .collection('chats')
            .snapshots(), 
        builder: (ctx, streamSnapshot) {
          if (streamSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }

          return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: streamSnapshot.data,   **//not able to add .documents.length after this**
              itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text('This is working'),
                  ));
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Try `streamSnapshot.data!.docs.length`, make sure data is not null.

Comment: That did not worked I just tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the type of your object on your StreamBuilder like this :

```
StreamBuilder<YourObject>
```

After that, you will access to the `documents` from the `streamSnapshot`

Comment: I am getting this error if I do that - "The argument type 'Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream<String>?'. "

Comment: It's because you pass the wrong type. The `YourObject` type must be same than the snapshot type.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  StreamBuilder<dynamic>
```